# React best practice storing images on server

Tags: reactjs, database, image, file, flask

Hey I am using react with a flask backend and I am trying to have a Form where users can upload images which should send to the backend and stored in database.
So this is my approach but I am not sure which format is the best to store it in the db.
And is FormData even a good solution?

```
 // updates thumbnail in state when new file is selected
  handleFileSelect = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      thumbnail: event.target.files[0],
    });
  };

  // File Upload
  handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", this.state.thumbnail, this.state.thumbnail);
    axios.post("url", fd).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If `axios` is the way your going, then i would recommend having a component that does the file upload functionality with an `onChange` to listen to the `event.target.files` and an input type of `file`. Maybe even add in the accepted types through the html attribute `accept`.

You can use `FileReader`, allowing you to read the content of the files stored on the users computer (async). Using this as a separate function, you can use that `FileReader` method to extract Base64
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

**Fetching the form data:**

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
```

**Then your `axios` would look something like this**

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    data: dataForm,
    url: 'urlhere',
    onUploadProgress: (ev: ProgressEvent) => {
        //Uploading progress functionality here....
    },
})
.then((resp) => {
    fetchBase64(file, (uri: string) => {
        //maybe set a useState here for the Image URI or upload status.
    });
})
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**Progress function:**

```
const progressPercentage = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
```